# Update Timeline view

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, scheduler

In my devexpress scheduler I use the timelineview to show the appointments and the time scales are taked from my database the sacles are loaded fine when I run the application but then I change the hours let's say that the start time is at 9am then I changed to 10am after is stored I use `scheduler.Refresh()` or `scheduler.RefreshData()` but the time line doesn't change the start hour, still show 9am as start time but all the logic I use detect 10am as start time, not the layout.

I found one way to show the changes, using `Application.Restart()` but Is there another way to acomplih this?

any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer these - [How to refresh XtraScheduler ?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q304881), [example xtrascheduler timeline view](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T360420)

Comment: Still can't acomplish this whitout `Application.Restart()` but thanks for the references.